# Feeds importer pass header values when fetching feed

Tags: 7, feeds, importing-exporting

We have been importing nodes with [feeds importer](https://www.drupal.org/project/feed_import) from XML for awhile on this website and now the feed has been changed to a new XML but this time it's *password/username* protected. The XML feed is literally the same with the exception of a couple new fields.

When I used this XML feed inside of a custom module, I simply pass the *username/password* into a header of the curl call to authenticate. I currently cannot find the appropriate area to pass header values in within feeds import.

My question would be, is there any support for username/password authentication when pulling in a XML file with a HTTP Fetcher, with Feeds import? Are there any contrib modules that could extend feeds importer to provide the functionality i desire?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[feeds httpfetcher append headers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_httpfetcher_append_headers) was the module I needed. Once i switched the fetcher I was able to pass in the **password** & **user name** into the get request to authenticate the request.

Comment: How to you set the key values? Any example? I don't know how to set up the headers inside the feed httpfetcher append headers modules

Comment: Solved, the problem was a empty final line in the textarea of configuration, passing the 
`Authorization|Basic thesecretEncodedtext==`
works